# Facebook feed sharing on wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, feed, sharing

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

I am trying to use that to have a share button on my content-blog.php page in wordpress. So on all the post excerpts that come up each one can be shared.

But if i put in the `<?php the_permalink() ?>` or `<?php the_title() ?>` in the appropriate sections they all have the same link and title.

Does anyone know how to make sure each button shares the appropriate stuff?

My site is dontstopdreaming.net you can see what happens when you click on the 'post to feed' text it will come up with same stuff for each post. Apart from the wrong data everything else is fine i have the app id and everything prepared.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links) instead, for your case?

Comment: Ill try it out and see how it goes thanks.

Comment: doesnt seem to be sharing the correct description

Comment: Have you added the [Open Graph tags](http://ogp.me/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a.) Your site news/posts to facebook page/profile:

1. There is offical Facebook plugin for wordpress. It will solve your issue.
   https://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/
2. The best wordpress to social networks plugin: 
   http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/

other; 45+ useful wordpress plugins for facebook.-> http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/06/best-wordpress-facebook-plugins.html

b.) Facebook feeds to your site

1. This plugin -> http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-feed-grabber/
2. This widget-> http://wordpress.org/plugins/fbf-facebook-page-feed-widget/

other; http://wordpress.org/plugins/jsl3-facebook-wall-feed/, http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-facebook-feed/